# Structure pointer pointer issue; doubly linked list related

Tags: c, pointers

Well, I got unexpected pointer shifts in some situations, such as this: there is a function inserting a new node into the list before the given element. While inserting, it makes before_which point at another node, which is not supposed to happen.

In fact, while typing this message I realised that using DList *before_which has no point and fixed everything by replacing it with DList before_which -- but now I'm curious: why does using a pointer pointer cause such things?

```
    typedef struct DListStruct {
        Pointer data;
        struct DListStruct *prev;
        struct DListStruct *next;
    } *DList;

    int dlist_insert_prev (DList *before_which, Pointer ins_value) {
        if (*before_which) {
            DList new_element=malloc(sizeof(struct DListStruct));
            if (!new_element) return 0;

            //[The part causing problems]
            if((*before_which)->prev) {
                new_element->data = ins_value;
                new_element->prev = (*before_which)->prev;
                new_element->next = *before_which;
                (*before_which)->prev->next = new_element;
                (*before_which)->prev = new_element;
                return 1;
            }
            //[/The part causing problems]
            else {  //This one is OK. Insertion into the beginning of the list
                new_element->data = (*before_which)->data;
                new_element->next = (*before_which)->next;
                new_element->prev = *before_which;
                (*before_which)->next->prev = new_element;
                (*before_which)->next = new_element;
                (*before_which)->data = ins_value;
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

A diagram here:
[image: Diagram]

There's a mistake: the pointer at the picture should be *before_which instead of just before_which

UPD: For comparison, a working version. Nothing has changed but the type of the argument.

```
    int dlist_insert_prev (DList before_which, Pointer ins_value) {
        if (before_which) {
            DList new_element=malloc(sizeof(struct DListStruct));
            if (!new_element) return 0;

            if(before_which->prev) {
                new_element->data = ins_value;
                new_element->prev = before_which->prev;
                new_element->next = before_which;
                before_which->prev->next = new_element;
                before_which->prev = new_element;
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                new_element->data = before_which->data;
                new_element->next = before_which->next;
                new_element->prev = before_which;
                before_which->next->prev = new_element;
                before_which->next = new_element;
                before_which->data = ins_value;
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The library GObject has a type GList which is a well defined doubley linked list, the functions defined to deal with Glist will get rid of all your bugs just like that.

Comment: I've dealt with the bug. The question is mainly why this thing refuses to work with a double pointer, but works perfectly with a simple pointer. Anyway, thanks for a good code example